# error : binary '>>' : no operator found which takes a right-hand operand of type 'const char [1] And program crashes after taking first input

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a simple program which takes 2 numbers, reverses them and prints their reversed sum. I have 2 problems

1. If I keep using "cin >> " it gives error "binary >> :no operator found which take a right hand operand of type 'const char[1](or there is no acceptable version )" .
2. If I use "scanf_s()" instead of "cin >> " then it crashes after taking the first number.

   ```
   int calculate_sum(string num){
   stack<char> mystack;
   int sum = 0;
   for (int i = 0; i < num.length(); i++){
       mystack.push(i);
   }

   while (!mystack.empty()){
       char c; int n;
       c = mystack.top();
       mystack.pop();
       n= (int)c;
       sum = sum + n;
   }

   int main(){
       cout << "Enter testcases:" << endl;
       int testcase=0;
       cin >> testcase;
       while (testcase--){
           string num1, num2;
           int rev_sum1, rev_sum2, final_sum;
           int sum = 0;
           cin >> num1 >> "" >> num2 ;
           //scanf_s("%s %s", num1, num2);
           rev_sum1 = calculate_sum(num1);
           rev_sum2 = calculate_sum(num2);
           final_sum = rev_sum1 + rev_sum2;
           cout << final_sum << endl;
       }
       return sum;
   }
   ```

Comment: `cin >> "" ` What does this mean?

Comment: Isn't the sum the same regardless of direction?

Comment: Posting to S.O. seems to be taking the place of basic debugging these days...   `scanf_s("%s %s", num1, num2)` Scan 2 strings into memory as specified by 2 uninitialized ints.

Comment: it's a mistake . it's cin >> num1 >> num2 ;

Comment: Your code has mismatched braces. Make sure you copy-paste the exact code that is giving the trouble.

Comment: Your `calculate_sum` returns the sum of the digits in a number. This is the same regardless of order. You're missing a crucial step. (Why is it called "calculate_sum" if it's supposed to reverse a number? Something like "reverse_number" would make more sense.)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with this line:

```
cin >> num1 >> "" >> num2 ;
```

You cannot store the value got from the input into `""`. I believe you wanted something like:

```
cin >> num1 >> num2 ;
```

Comment: i have changed this to cin >> num1 >> num2  ; removed the sum variable of the main function . And initialized every variable . but still i am not getting correct output . can u help ?

Comment: What errors do you get now? It seems you are not closing calculate_sum and not returning an int value from that function.

Comment: no i have returned the sum . it's  a copy mistake . please see the full code here  http://pastebin.com/9txkwS3i

Comment: I believe you are missing the multiplication by ten in your algorithm. Can you give me some example inputs and example outputs?